# Element not intractable error when running full code block, however works in snippets

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am populating a webform online, and wrote a script on selenium to complete this process. When running the code in snippets it works without a problem.

However, when I try to run the full block of code I get "ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable"

I have narrowed it down to two fields that are triggering this issue, which are vehical_make, and vehival_model. I thought possibly this could be due to the page not loading properly so I added driver.implicitly_wait(10) line, but to no avail the issue persist.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("-headless")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\GP8535\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Conda_folder\Scripts\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=option)
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.lowestrates.ca/insurance/auto")


# Populate ZipCode field

zipcode=driver.find_element_by_id('postal-code-field').send_keys("M4C 5C6")
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input.btn.secondary').click()


# Vehical Information
vehical_year=driver.find_element_by_id("vehicle-year0").send_keys("2017")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
vehical_make=driver.find_element_by_id("vehicle-make0").send_keys("CADILLAC")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)                                
vehical_model=driver.find_element_by_id("vehicle-model0").send_keys("XTS 4DR")
vehical_leased=driver.find_element_by_id("is-leased0").send_keys("No")
vehical_purchase_month=driver.find_element_by_id("acquired-month0").send_keys("January")
vehical_purchase_year=driver.find_element_by_id("acquired-year0").send_keys("2018")
daily_distance=driver.find_element_by_id("daily-distance0").send_keys("500")
kilometers_year=driver.find_element_by_id("annual-distance0").send_keys("20")
next_page1=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.has-spinner').click()


#Driver Information

first_name=driver.find_element_by_id("first-name0").send_keys("Bob")
dob_month=driver.find_element_by_id("dob-month0").send_keys("May")
dob_day=driver.find_element_by_id("dob-day0").send_keys("11")
dob_year=driver.find_element_by_id("dob-year0").send_keys("1992")

first_insure_year=driver.find_element_by_id("first-insured-year0").send_keys("2009")
time_with_insured=driver.find_element_by_id("time-with-insurer0").send_keys("3")
next_page2=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.has-spinner').click()
```

Comment: Not sure why you marked this as duplicate, and then linked two answers one of which I tried as stated in the desription, and the other which is irrelevant?

Comment: what if you run this on interactive mode not headless? still getting the same issue?

Comment: Yes, the same issue persist.

Comment: I can't add any answer.If possible place one more question.